# Smooth tracking mouse moves

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, sass

How can i add smooth track for mouse move? Like on this example? [example](https://www.marvinx.com/fr/)

I have'd try. That was my codepen codepen
Maybe some one know the way. I try to use not only left and top parametr, right and bottom with delay, but it worst

Answer (score 1):

The Example You Showed is of a website made with combination of 3-JS (a 3D library of Java Script) and Java Script but you can create a website with smooth scroll just add this to your CSS.

```
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: i dont need smooth scroll, i cant add my codepen link, and code not correct inserting. https://codepen.io/jukachu/pen/yLvdarM